# Amazon S3 copy the directory to another directory

Tags: amazon-s3, directory

How do I copy/duplicate a folder that contain sub-folders and files into another directory within the S3 bucket using PHP API?

`$s3->copy_object` only copies the folder, but not the files and sub-folders inside.

Do I have to use `$s3->list_objects` to get all files and directory and run `$s3->copy_object` on every single file/directory?

Comment: +1 for the question. One might or might not understand the resource path S3 concept, but the request is totally valid. Maybe the question is if S3 supports copying resources internally (or creating multiple paths for the same resource, why not?) somehow? If there are a lot of files, it would really be ridiculous to have to download them all and re-upload...

Answer (score 19):

S3 is not a filesystem, it's an object store. Folders don't actually exist in any tangible sense; a folder is just something you can call a shared prefix. Put another way, if you create `path/to/one` and `path/to/two`, it doesn't also cause `path` and `path/to` to exist. If you see them, that's because some component took a list of objects, split their keys on `/`, and decided to display that list as a hierarchy.

You want to "duplicate a folder into another folder". Rephrasing this into S3 terms, you want to "duplicate all objects with the same prefix into objects with a different prefix". Saying it that way makes the method clear: get a list of objects with the one prefix, then copy each of them.

Comment: And yet `aws s3 cp -R` manages to do it in a single command

Answer (score 3):

Code for scala (copying between folders in one bucket):

```
def copyFolders(bucketName: String, srcFolder: String, targetFolder: String): Unit = {
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val transferManager: TransferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard.build
try {

  for (file <- s3.listObjects(bucketName, s"$srcFolder/").getObjectSummaries) {
    val fileName = file.getKey.replace(s"$srcFolder/", "")
    if (!fileName.isEmpty) {
      val transferProcess: Copy = transferManager.copy(bucketName, file.getKey,
        bucketName, s"$targetFolder/$fileName")
      log.info(s"Old key = ${file.getKey}")
      log.info(s"New file Key = $targetFolder/$fileName")
      transferProcess.waitForCompletion()
    }
  }
} catch {
  case e: AmazonServiceException =>
    log.error(e.getErrorMessage, e)
    System.exit(1)
  case e: AmazonClientException =>
    log.error("Amazon client error: " + e.getMessage, e)
    System.exit(1)
  case e: InterruptedException =>
    log.error("Transfer interrupted: " + e.getMessage, e)
    System.exit(1)
}
}
```

Usage:

```
copyFolders("mybucket", "somefolder/srcfolder", "somefolder/targetfolder")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `@aws-sdk/client-s3`, here is the full js code:

```
import {
    S3Client,
    CopyObjectCommandInput,
    CopyObjectCommand,
    ListObjectsCommandInput,
    ListObjectsCommand
} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
  
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-1' });

const listS3Objects = async (input: ListObjectsCommandInput) => {
     const command = new ListObjectsCommand(input);
     return await s3Client.send(command);
}

const copyS3Object = async (input: any) => {
    const command = new CopyObjectCommand(input);
    return await s3Client.send(command);
};

export const copyFolder = async (fromBucket:string, fromFolderKey:string, toBucket:string, toFolderKey: any) => {
      
try {
    const listObjectsResponse = await listS3Objects({
        Bucket: fromBucket,
        Prefix: `${fromFolderKey}/`
    })

    const fromObjectKeys = listObjectsResponse.Contents.map(content => content.Key)

    for (let fromObjectKey of fromObjectKeys) {
        const toObjectKey = fromObjectKey.replace(fromFolderKey, toFolderKey);

       await copyS3Object({
          Bucket: toBucket,
          CopySource: `${fromBucket}/${fromObjectKey}`,
          Key: toObjectKey,
       })
    }
  } catch (error) {
     throw new Error(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using list objects and move each object one by one. Another way is to use s3fuse, which will make your s3 bucket as the local directory and then you can just apply simple command like 'mv' to move the files.

Answer (score 0):

here is some code taken right from amazon. This code duplicates the item a three times to a target, what you need to do is change it so that it loops through each key and add it to the batch.

```
<?php

// Include the AWS SDK using the Composer autoloader.
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$sourceBucket = '*** Your Source Bucket Name ***';
$sourceKeyname = '*** Your Source Object Key ***';
$targetBucket = '*** Your Target Bucket Name ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => "{$sourceKeyname}-copy",
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
));

// Perform a batch of CopyObject operations.
$batch = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $batch[] = $s3->getCommand('CopyObject', array(
        'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
        'Key'        => "{$sourceKeyname}-copy-{$i}",
        'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
    ));
}
try {
    $successful = $s3->execute($batch);
    $failed = array();
} catch (\Guzzle\Service\Exception\CommandTransferException $e) {
    $successful = $e->getSuccessfulCommands();
    $failed = $e->getFailedCommands();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a java solution using the aws sdk:

```
public static void copyAllFilesWithPrefix(AmazonS3 s3Client,
                                          String srcBucket,
                                          String srcPrefix,
                                          String destBucket,
                                          String destPrefix) {
    ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(srcBucket, srcPrefix);
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
        S3Object srcFile = s3Client.getObject(srcBucket, objectSummary.getKey());
        String destKey = srcFile.getKey().replace(srcPrefix, destPrefix);
        if (!s3Client.doesObjectExist(destBucket, destKey)) {
            copyFile(s3Client, srcFile, destBucket, srcFile.getKey().replace(srcPrefix, destPrefix));
        }
    }
}
```